# How to create cursor inside procedure body in plsql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I want create **cursor inside procedure body dynamically** also i have to use **for loop** instead of below code. i did the dynamic cursor but i cannot use the for loop.

```
PROCEDURE myprocedure
AS
  LV_TEST_CUR SYS_REFCURSOR;
  LV_QUERY VARCHAR2(200);
  LV_DATE  DATE;
BEGIN
  LV_QUERY:='select sysdate as mydate from dual';
  OPEN LV_TEST_CUR FOR LV_QUERY;
  /*FOR CUR_VAR IN LV_TEST_CUR
  LOOP
  dbms_output.put_line(CUR_VAR.mydate);
  end LOOP;
  */
  LOOP
    FETCH LV_TEST_CUR INTO LV_DATE;
    EXIT
  WHEN LV_TEST_CUR%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(LV_DATE);
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE LV_TEST_CUR;
END myprocedure;
```

if i am using commented code(for loop), i getting error

> PLS-00221: is not a procedure or is undefined.

Is it possible using for loop in dynamic cursor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you cannot reference a cursor variable in a cursor FOR loop

but you can use the select statment direct:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE myprocedure
AS
  LV_TEST_CUR SYS_REFCURSOR;
  LV_QUERY VARCHAR2(200);
  LV_DATE  DATE;
BEGIN
  FOR CUR_VAR IN (select sysdate as mydate from dual)
  LOOP
  dbms_output.put_line(CUR_VAR.mydate);
  end LOOP;

END myprocedure;
/
```

Comment: i think it is good alternative for the about procedure. it will simply my code

Comment: What if I need to create multiple cursor inside loop?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the `FOR <row> IN <cursor> LOOP` syntax with dynamic SQL; see [the example in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/appdev.112/e10472/dynamic.htm#i13057), which shows the method you're using when that code is commented out anyway.

Your example doesn't need to be dynamic at all, but I assume you've just simplified it for this question. If it had a placeholder then there would be nowhere to set its value. If you had:

```
LV_QUERY:='select sysdate - :days as mydate from dual';
FOR CUR_VAR IN LV_TEST_CUR LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(CUR_VAR.mydate);
END LOOP;
```

... then the `FOR ... IN ...` version doesn't give you anywhere to assign a value to the `days` placeholder. You have to use the dynamic `OPEN` to do that:

```
LV_QUERY:='select sysdate - :days as mydate from dual';
-- pass '1' as the bind variable
OPEN LV_TEST_CUR FOR LV_QUERY USING 1;
LOOP
    FETCH LV_TEST_CUR INTO LV_DATE;
    EXIT WHEN LV_TEST_CUR%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(LV_DATE);
END LOOP;
CLOSE LV_TEST_CUR;
```

Of course you may not need a placeholder, and are just building the query string dynamically, but the restriction still applies.

Comment: Yes you are correct, i simplified the code for the question. i understood for loop we can't use in this scenario

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware you can't use a FOR loop with a cursor variable or "ref cursor".  FOR loops are only for use with hard-coded SQL statements or cursors.
See the section on cursor variable restrictions [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/static.htm#i40146) where it explicitly states "...you cannot reference a cursor variable in a cursor FOR loop".